# Why do I get a TypeError that says: missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, typeerror

If I run this code:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, ctx, message):
    if message.content.startswith('/test'):
        ctx.send("Test")
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you add the code that is calling the function?

Comment: The function is called, when someone writes a message on Discord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written in the docs, on_message only takes 1 argument: `message`. Since your listener seems to be in a class, it will only take `self` and `message`.

If you remove the `ctx` from the arguments it should work. Obviously the `ctx.send` will not work then, you can use `message.channel.send` as a substitute. Also make sure to use `await` for sending a message.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.content.startswith('/test'):
        await message.channel.send("Test")
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message